# Detecting unused Django template libraries

Tags: python, django

While rendering a template is there a way to make Django log something when unused tag libraries are loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could fold in your own load method into the django template language and add in a logmethod using Django logging, just out of curiosity, is it the complexity of the template variety that a logger makes it more conveinient to keep the helicopter view?

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I would do, although this may not be the best solution.

1. Write a script that goes through all of your urls.py files and builds up a tree of all the urls that exist in your project (I know there is a third-party django plugin to list all urls, but I cant seem to remember what it is)
2. Build a unittest that takes the list generated in (1), using the Client() to hit every url, and then query the response objects for the templates which were rendered.
3. Perform a logical AND with the list of total HTML files in your template directory and the list generated from this unit test.

Comment: This will not yield a list of unused tag libraries. It will yield a list of unused template files.

Comment: @Martin This not guaranteed to do even that because views may conditionally use different templates.